# tomcat with https get a CLOSE_WAIT when directly TCP connect

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, tcp

I use tomcat 8.5.4 to build a https based server on port 443 like this:

```
 94     <Connector
 95            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
 96            port="8000" maxThreads="200"
 97            scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
 98            keystoreFile="conf/rs_keystore.jks" keystorePass="ntsdawn"
 99            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

But a client use tcp to connect the port 8000, and then quickly close the tcp connection. After this, in my server the connection is CLOSE_WAIT status, and more important is, the CPU grows and the org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TLSClientHelloExtractor object was created very fast util the gc trigger:

```
root@nts32:/home/vcloud/apache-tomcat-8.5.4/logs# jmap -histo 14 | head

 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:       5159655      165108960  java.util.HashMap$Node
   2:          9138      131509512  [I
   3:       5148446      123562704  java.util.ArrayList
   4:       5145501      123492024  java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$Node
   5:       5145486      123491664  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.**TLSClientHelloExtractor**
   6:       3210008      102720256  java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Node
   7:       2162508       86500320  java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator
```

And the connection will stay at CLOSE_WAIT forever....

But, if I modify the server.xml use http but not https like this:

```
 70     <Connector port="8000" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
 71                connectionTimeout="20000"
 72                redirectPort="8443" />
```

Then every thing is OK. The TCP connect come and my server will reply the FIN when client send the FIN.

Is anything wrong of my https configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in **tomcat 8.5.4** wherein TLS connections get into a loop when socket connection is dropped before TLS handshake is complete. Upgrading to **tomcat 8.5.5 or above** should fix this.

Below is the bug

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60035

Answer (score 1):

There could be issue with HTTPs apache libs as well. From apache release notes of httpcore-osgi-4.4.11, I found two bugs fixed in "httpcore-osgi" library which are possibly related: 
    Bug fix: corrected handling of graceful SSL session termination initiated by the opposite endpoint
    (back-ported from master).
    Contributed by Oleg Kalnichevski

```
Bug fix: corrected handling of NEED_WRAP handshake status during graceful SSL session termination
(back-ported from master).
Contributed by Oleg Kalnichevski <olegk at apache.org>
```

Link for reference: https://www.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpcore/RELEASE_NOTES-4.4.x.txt